# Get Node Names by a specific depths

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml, xsd

What I am trying to do is given a depth return the nodes names at that depth. I do not care about the information at that level just the element name.

so given 1 it would only return BookStoreInfo and Book

given 2 it would return just Address,Tel,Fax,BookName,ISBN

```
<BookStore>
  <BookStoreInfo>
    <Address />
    <Tel />
    <Fax />
 <BookStoreInfo>
 <Book>
    <BookName />
    <ISBN />
  <PublishDate />
 </Book>
 <Book>
 ....
 </Book>
</BookStore>
```

This is what I am currently trying. When I do a count of the nodes it returns 11 which is correct, but when I display the nodes it shows the nodes and everything in them which I do not want

```
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(doc);
        var AnswersScript = doc.Document.Element("root").Nodes();

        int count = 0;

        foreach (var node in AnswersScript)
        {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine(node);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
```

Comment: Let's see what you have tried so far.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this?  Do you really have an XML file whose contents are _completely_ unknown to you?  Parsing such a thing could prove to be quite complicated.  A little background on this situation, or at least the goal, would help.

Comment: the xml I have can be dynamic based on different variables which are unknown to me. I have no documentation to work with and no one who knows how this works. I am trying to create a way to potentially compare different xml files based on the passed in parameters. There is apparently no known mechanism to parse this as well.

Comment: That's going to be tough, if it's realistic at all.  XML is by nature not rigidly structured, so to analyze it on-the-fly and then compare it to something else...  Wow.

Answer (score 0):

Here if half the answer to my question

```
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"..\..\doc.xml");
        var AnswersScript = doc.Document.Element("root").Elements();

        int count = 0;

        foreach (var node in AnswersScript)
        {
            count++;
            if (doc.Document.Element("root").Element(node.Name).Elements().Count() > 1)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(node.Name);
            }
            else
            {}
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

that gives you the element nodes now I am trying to think of a way to parse through this dynamically without hard coding the depths